# Tree of java objects based on a list of strings representing hierarchy

Tags: java, tree, hierarchy

I have an interesting and as I understand not the easiest task.

I need to create a tree of objects based on a list of strings representing hierarchy.

For example, strings in the list are (actually it could be any graph):

```
List<String> hierarchies;
```

1#
1#2#
1#2#3#
1#2#4#
1#2#4#5#

Class I have:

```
class Tree {

    List<Tree> children;

    // here is getter

}
```

I have some implementation but only for start. I don't know how to finish this code. Can you share your vision with me?

Thanks in advance!

```
Tree tree = null;

for (String hierarchy : hierarchies) {

    if (hierarchy.equals("1#")) {
        tree = new Tree();
    } else {
        tree.getChildren().add(new Tree());
    }

}

return tree;
```

Comment: Can you draw an image (in ASCII art) how the tree should look like, given the example input you provided?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible solutions. With no complexity it may look like:

```
public void testHierarchy() {

    List<String> hierarchies = new ArrayList<String>();

    hierarchies.add("1#");
    hierarchies.add("1#2#");
    hierarchies.add("1#2#3#");
    hierarchies.add("1#2#4#");
    hierarchies.add("1#2#4#5#");

    Tree root = new Tree();
    for (String hierarchy : hierarchies) {
        String[] elHierarchy = hierarchy.split("#");
        processLevel(elHierarchy, root);
    }
}

private void processLevel(String[] hierarchy, Tree rootTree) {

    if (null == rootTree.getValue() || "".equals(rootTree.getValue())) {
        rootTree.setValue(hierarchy[0]);
    }

    Tree nextChild = null;
    for (Tree child : rootTree.getChildren()) {
        if (child.getValue().equals(hierarchy[1])) {
            nextChild = child;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hierarchy.length > 1) {
        if (null == nextChild) {
            nextChild = new Tree();
            nextChild.setValue(hierarchy[1]);
            rootTree.getChildren().add(nextChild);
        }
        String[] remainHierarchy = new String[hierarchy.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(hierarchy, 1, remainHierarchy, 0,  remainHierarchy.length);
        processLevel(remainHierarchy, nextChild);
    }
}

private static class Tree {
    String  value;
    List<Tree>  children    = new ArrayList<SometestTest.Tree>();

    public List<Tree> getChildren() {

        return children;
    }

    public String getValue() {

        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

P.S. Not too elegant but simple.

Comment: Vadim, it really helped. Thank you a lot!